# Alerting a user that two fields are the same

Tags: ms-access

Is there any way I can let a user know that the field in the current record is identical to the field in another record? Because 99% of the time they will be different, but 1% of the time there will have to be two records with the same field, so I want a way to alert the user and just make sure they are aware of that in case they did not mean to do it.

Comment: Yes. Hints: Use DLookup in the AfterUpdate event of the control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a Function and call it as needed. In your case in the AfterUpdate of the control as @Andre mentioned above.

```
Public Function IsDuplicate(ByVal Value As String) As Boolean
    IsDuplicate = (DCount("*", "TableName", "FieldName='" & Value & "'") > 1)
End Function
```

You can call it like this:

```
Private Sub Text0_AfterUpdate()
    If IsDuplicate(Me.Text0.Value) Then
        MsgBox "Value exists..."
    End If
End Sub
```